# How to Create Active Record Associations for Team functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

When viewing a user's Show page, I Would like to display the teams the user is on followed by the number of members on each team.  I am trying to understand how to write methods in the model for this functionality to happen.

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :team_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :user_id
  belongs_to :admin, :class_name => "User",:foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, source: :user
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
  has_many :memberships
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20140211214838) do


create_table "memberships", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "team_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end


create_table "teams", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "encrypted_password", :default => "", :null => false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer "sign_in_count", :default => 0, :null => false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.string "image_file_name"
  t.string "image_content_type"
  t.integer "image_file_size"
  t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  t.string "username"
  t.string "bio"
  t.string "location"
end

end
```

Comment: Just iterate over `@user.teams`, and then output a team's `members` count? You already have the associations there, you just need to use them.

Comment: i agree with @sevenseacat, if you need some code in order to show these values in the view, you'll need to go through a proper tutorial on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have the associations in place, you just need to iterate over the teams in the view. E.g something like:

```
# users/show.html.erb
...
<% @user.teams.each do |team| %>
 <div><%= "#{team.name} (#{team.members.count})" %></div>
<% end %>
...
```

Depending on what else you're doing with the teams and members data, for performance reasons it may be a good idea to [eager load](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) some of the associations with the user.

Comment: Thank you for the eager load advice!